# Initial list gettign modified if duplicate list is modified

Tags: java, list

My problem is I have an initial list called `currentComponents`. I am copying it's items in another new list called `currentMonitorComponents`. But when the components in `currentMonitorComponents` are modified automatically the items in `currentComponents` list are also modified. My code is something like this ---

```
 List<MonitorComponent> currentMonitorComponents = new ArrayList<MonitorComponent>();
        currentMonitorComponents.addAll(currentComponents);
```

Comment: from your code, it doesn't look like you have shallow copy. It looks good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a deep copy of your list:

```
 ArrayList<MonitorComponent> currentComponentsClone = new ArrayList<MonitorComponent>();
 for(MonitorComponent m : currentMonitorComponents)
    currentComponentsClone.add(m.clone());
```

And to implement `clone` method in your class:

```
public class MonitorComponent{

    String s;
    Date d;
    ...

    public MonitorComponent clone(){
        MonitorComponent m = new MonitorComponent();
        m.s = this.s.clone();
        m.d = this.d.clone();
        ...
        return m;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

at the end these both have same elements(MonitorComponent).. they are pointing to same objects in memory.. You have to make clone of every MonitorComponent inside the list..

You will need to iterate on the items, and clone them one by one, putting the clones in your result arraylist as you go.

```
public static List<MonitorComponent> cloneList(List<MonitorComponent> list) {
    List<MonitorComponent> clone = new ArrayList<MonitorComponent>(list.size());
    for(MonitorComponent item: list) clone.add(item.clone());
    return clone;
}
```

For that to work, obviously, you will have to get your MonitorComponent object to implement the Cloneable interface, and the clone() method.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is creating a shallow copy. You have a new list, but the elements are the same objects, not copies of the objects. So if you modify one of the objects you can see the changes via both lists.

You could alternatively make a deep(er) copy, by creating new objects for your new list which are copies of the objects from the first list. The exact you'd do this will depend on the type of objects in question. One option may be to use `clone()`. Another might be to invoke a copying constructor. You'd need to do this for each element of the origina list, and add the copy to your new list.

Answer (score 0):

When you "copy" elements from the original list to the new list, you're really copying the references contained in the original list, not the actual objects in the original list. Thus, the first element in each list really points at the same underlying object; thus, when you change that object using one list, the other list sees the change. It's sort of like having two "views" of the same underlying series of objects.

To fix this, you need to "clone" each of the objects you want to copy from the original list. There are a few ways of doing this, but in the end you have to be sure that at some point in your code the `new` keyword is used, `clone()` is called (the `clone()` method in Java, from what I've been told, though, should be avoided), or a constructor is called. That ensures that the objects you're putting into the second list are distinct from the originals.